# Which components do I need to host ASP MVC site on Google Cloud?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I'm hoping someone has ventured into hosting ASP MVC site *with* Google cloud *perhaps even leveraged google components with pricing*. Last week they released a [help guide on ASP MVC with Google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/hello-world), however it only accounts for Windows server and not ASP MVC with Linux. For me, the complexity comes in when I want to tap into other google components like bigquery etc.

I have 2 questions:

1. Technical: **Which google cloud components do I need** or select to host the ASP MVC site. (Since .NET is supported, I am talking about cloud sites, similar to Azure)
2. Compute Pricing: Given that they have pricing based on [compute engine/app eninge etc](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/). How do I estimate/calculate the pricing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the web site and how much you want to configure yourself.

The compute engine is an infrastructure as a service environment, where you will have to configure and manage all the resources you require.  This is the cheapest, most flexible option, but requires the overhead of configuring the VM's yourself.  You'll need to use the compute engine to configure your .net application. Take a look at [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) and this will help with a Linux instance [Quickstart Using a Linux VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux)

The app engine provides a Platform as a Service meaning you just deploy and platform manages resources.  This will cost more, but will manage code for some popular languages like Java, Python, PHP or Go (unfortunately .net is not covered).  Take a look at [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/)

If you have a data storage need for your site, the you'll have to decide what you want to store and how.

- Cloud Storage for fully managed data store holding images, blobs and unstructured data.
- Cloud Data Store for semi structured NoSQL data.
- Cloud SQL for MySQL instance, useful for OLTP
- BigQuery for analytic / enterprise data warehouse projects

You can read about the various data store option [Google Cloud Data Store Options](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/)

In regards to the cost element of your question, you'll have to overlay your requirements onto Google's offerings to build up an estimate.  Unfortunately, not having a relevant app engine option will complicate that for you